# Waiting for promise to resolve before loading resource

Tags: angularjs, promise

One of my AngularJS controllers contains this line:

```
api.tickets.query()
```

the `api` module contains this:

```
angular.module('myapp.api', [
  'ngResource'
])

.factory('api', function($resource, applicationsService) {

  function fetchAppId() {
    return applicationsService.getCurrentApp();
  }

  return {
    tickets: $resource('tickets', {
      applicationId: fetchAppId
    }),
    ...
  }
```

applicationsService.getCurrentApp() makes an $http call itself. So you can perhaps see the problem - this call may not have resolved by the time fetchAppId() returns.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets say data that returns from `applicationsService` by async way is:

```
var data = [{
    "PreAlertInventory": "5.000000",
    "SharesInInventory": "3.000000",
    "TotalSharesSold": "2.000000"
}];
```

and `applicationsService` factory returns promise:

```
.factory('applicationsService', ['$resource','$q',  function($resource, $q) {
    var data = [{
        "PreAlertInventory": "5.000000",
        "SharesInInventory": "3.000000",
        "TotalSharesSold": "2.000000"
    }];   
            
    var factory = {
        getCurrentApp: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();   
            
            deferred.resolve(data);
                                            
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

I would just call `api.tickets()`

```
$scope.data = api.tickets();
```

but our `api` service will look like:

```
.factory('api', function ($resource, applicationsService, $q, $timeout) {

    function fetchAppId() {
        return applicationsService.getCurrentApp();
    }

    return {
        tickets: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            fetchAppId().then(function (data) { // promise callback
                $timeout(function () {         // added dummy timeout to simulate delay
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }, 3000);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/661/)**</kbd>

Comment: Bingo, thanks Maxim, that worked like a charm. Appreciate the Fiddle and detail :)

Comment: I think it works because promise in $scopes are waited for the $apply() cycle to finish. As the documentation says "$q is integrated with the $rootScope.Scope Scope model observation mechanism in angular, which means faster propagation of resolution or rejection into your models and avoiding unnecessary browser repaints, which would result in flickering UI."

Comment: if some one using $resource for request, then we need to include $promise

fetchAppId().$promise.then(function(data) {  ---- });

Answer (score 4):

You need to do is create a promise your self.

```
.factory('api', function($resource, applicationsService,$q) {

  function fetchAppId() {
    return applicationsService.getCurrentApp();
  }

  return {
    tickets: function() {
        var defer=$q.defer();
        fetchAppId().then(function(data) {
             var appId=data;
             $resource('tickets', {applicationId: appId})
                 .then(function(data) {
                      defer.resolve(data);
                 })
        }
        return defer.promise;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for an angular resource (`$resource`) to be resolved before a route change, then you'll need to return the `$promise`.

```
$routeProvider.when('/tickets', {
    resolve: {
        'tickets': function ('Ticket') {
            // do this to resolve the async call prior to controller load
            return Ticket.query().$promise;

            // this will resolve 'tickets' during/after controller load
            return Ticket.query();
        }
    },
    controller: ...
});
```